# Why are function fields of $U\subset V$ are equal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $U\subset V$ be two affine varieties.

Define the function field of an affine variety $X$ to be 
$$
k(X)=\operatorname{Frac}(A(X))
$$

How to show that $k(U)=k(V)$?

In particular, if $U=\mathbb{V}(x,y), V=\mathbb{V}(x)$, I cannot see them are equal. For example, $\frac{1}{y-1}\in k(X)$, but seems not in $k(Y)$.

Comment: If $U$ is dense in $V$, then the function fields are the same.

Comment: @ZhenLin, could you give me a proof or a reference?

Comment: Just to be clear, the question is wrong: in your example $k(U)$ and $k(V)$ are different. As Zhen Lin says, it's only true if $U$ is dense in $V$. Shafarevich Volume 1 will explain this in detail.